# Why is my onclick event not executing?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple button that executes a javascript function on click. The button seems to be refreshing the page, and the js code is not executing at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Dynamic Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="col-sm-12 blog-main">
    <form class="form-addCards form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="col-xs-2" id="submitBtn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submit();">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="newSet.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the js:

```
function submit(){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("hit");
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the debugger for errors? `event` is probably not defined, since you're not passing it as an argument to the function.

Comment: `event` isn't a global variable (anymore). It's an argument passed to the event handler. With `onevent` attributes, you'll have to pass it along to any functions that need to use it – `onclick="submit(event)"`. And, have them accept it – `function submit(event)`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think its,becuse submit is a built in function for the form.  Try calling your function something else, or add id to your button and attach onclick using jquery on method.

$('#buttonid').on('click', function() { // do stuff });